# How many passwords are possible

Tags: math, passwords, permutation, combinations

The password must conform to the following rules, how many different passwords are possible?

- 6-8 characters
- At least one number
- At least one special character (US keyboard)
- At least two uppercase characters

What i have is:
10 numbers 
36 special characters
26 lowercase
26 uppercase

So working backwards, I have

Does this make sense or should i not count down since it doesn't matter if the characters are different?

so I think it could either be:
(26*25*36*10*98*97*96*95)-(26*25*36*10*98*97)=2.028434008 x 10^13

or

(26*26*36*10*98*98*98*98)-(26*26*36*10*98*98*)=2.244444143 x 10^13

repeats dont matter

Comment: What are you trying to figure out?  Say the answer is 150 billion.  What does that tell you?

Comment: number of combinations for a brute force attack/time for the attack to take place

Comment: And what does that help you with?  Say there are 150 billion.  What then?

Comment: @user1093111 - If the brute force attacker does not know these parameters, the number of possibilities are far higher, as they have to try the full character set (98 choices).  `(98)^6 + (98)^7 + (98)^8`

Comment: Then it would make sense for a attacker to do the attack as long as there isnt an automatic password reset in less time?

Comment: Using the numbers from @Aiias's answer i'm getting 22,678,137,256,320 possibilities. Even if an attacker could test 100,000 combinations per second, the worst case scenario for a brute force attack is over 7 years if i'm working out correctly.. ouch. Of course a real brute force attack would not take a naive approach, and I suspect the majority of real-world passwords are poor quality - say, contain a dictionary word, dumping things to satisfy the numbers/symbols quota at the end, capitalising the first letter. Never know it might even get it in one guess -> "Pas$w0rD" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possibilities should be something like this:

**6 characters:**
(10) * (36) * (26) * (26) * (98) * (98) = `A`

**7 characters:**
(10) * (36) * (26) * (26) * (98) * (98) * (98) = `B`

**8 characters:**
(10) * (36) * (26) * (26) * (98) * (98) * (98) * (98) = `C`

So the total possibilities would be `A + B + C`.

Derived from:

(10) = enforce at least one choice is a number, only 10 choices
(36) = enforce at least one choice is a special character, only 36 choices
(26) * (26) = enforce at least two choices are uppercase letters, only 676 choices
(98) = full character set (number, special character, uppercase letter, or lowercase letter)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you haven't considered the fact that the choices can be permuted.

Comment: As long as a password meets those requirements shouldn't order not matter?

Comment: @user1093111: if I understand your question correctly, then it shouldn't, but the above calculation assumes that it does.  Say you only had a 2-character password, one digit and one lowercase letter-- the above calculation would say there were 10*26 possibilities, but really there are 10*26*2.

Comment: @DSM that got cut off

Comment: @DSM unless you meant 10*26*"2"

Comment: 10*26*2, i.e. 520.  You can have the first be a digit and the second a lowercase letter, 10*26; or the first be a lowercase letter and the second a digit, 26*10.  The point is there are more possibilities than the above calculation suggests.